# How to use "mime" in vacation or vacation-seconds

Tags: dovecot, sieve-language

I'm using "Pigeonhole Sieve Interpreter" in dovecot(http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Pigeonhole/Sieve), but there is a problem for me!

I want to use html code in vacation, I find the mime params. But there is no example about it! I only find a example in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5230
in 4.4, but it is not work! Maybe,I have some mistake？
Who can give some more detail ?
Thanks!

Comment: :mime "MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\">
<HTML><HEAD><META http-equiv=Content-Type content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">
</HEAD><BODY>123</BODY></HTML>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vacation :subject "AutoReply${subjwas}"
         :seconds 10
         :handle "auto-resp" :mime "MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64

5aaI5aaI55qE5ZOHJm5ic3A7PGI+5Y2h5Y2h5Y2h5ZWK5ZWK77yBPC9iPg==";
```